# How do I handle not sending multiple requests to my database, if a request has already been sent?

Tags: sql, reactjs, stripe-payments

After completing payment, the user is redirected to a paymentStatus page that looks like this:

```
const PaymentStatus = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);

const {data: sendRequest} = useGlobalAxios("post", "request"); //custom hook to send req 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    const clientSecret: any = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }

    stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {

      switch (paymentIntent?.status) {
        case "succeeded":
          sendRequest("request", request);
          setMessage("success");
          break;
         // ...
          }
        });
  }, [stripe]);

  return <>{message == "success" ? <Success message={message} /> : null}</>;
}
```

The issue I'm currently facing is that, after the payment is successful and the payment status component runs, upon reloading the page, the component runs again. Consequently, the `succeeded` case is triggered once more, resulting in another request being sent to my server through the sendRequest() function.

I've come up with two solutions:

- Making `window.location.search` the dependency of the `useEffect`. However, the problem with this approach is that upon reloading, I don't have the opportunity to reset the `message` to "success." Consequently, the condition in my return statement fails.
- Checking with my server/db/postgres on every reload to verify if the request already exists. Although this could work, it feels excessive to send a request to my server with each reload just to address an issue that I believe should be handled on the client side.

Comment: Please do not spam tags. This question had nothing to do with postgres.

Comment: You can use some client side storage (localstorage / indexedDB) to save the already sent requests. Then before triggering the request, you can check here

Comment: @ALTHAFPJALEEL user can manipulate localstorage, and in my app they may have an incentive too.